# Keep track of visited URL - itsy crawler

Tags: clojure, web-crawler

I'm making an application in Clojure and I'm using itsy crawler to crawl specific site.

Now I'm wondering is it possible to run itsy crawler for some time, and then stop whole application, but when I start application again to skip already visited urls?

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the source, [itsy](https://github.com/dakrone/itsy) does not provide a built in mechanism for saving the current state of the crawler. But, the current state of the crawler is accessible in the result of the [`crawl`](https://github.com/dakrone/itsy/blob/master/src/itsy/core.clj#L212) function, under the `:state` key.

You could serialize the values in `:seen-urls` atom and `:queued-urls` queue on exiting your application, and then deserializing them when you start it again. It looks like you would have to add your saved values after running the `crawl` function, to make sure everything is initialized correctly.